# Proper configuration for VelocityView's Servlets to load resources in Jetty embedded?

Tags: java, jetty, velocity

I am switching embedded web servers for my app but cannot figure out how to get VelocityLayoutServlet to load its resources in Jetty. Every single request is a 404 and I'm out of ideas.

Note that an app requirement is for the servlet be accessible via root, IE http://example.com/index.vm. The server also must be embedded since its just a view into a running application.

Basic test code(BotVelocityServlet extends VelocityLayoutServlet so I can set context variables in `fillContext()`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    ServletContextHandler servletHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    servletHandler.addServlet(BotVelocityServlet.class, "/*");

    server.setHandler(servletHandler);
    server.start();
}
```

My `velocity.properties` which is loaded by Velocity according to the logs:

```
class.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader
runtime.log.logsystem.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute 
velocimacro.library.autoreload = true
velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline.to.replace.global = true
class.resource.loader.cache = false 
file.resource.loader.cache = false 
webapp.resource.loader.cache = false
webapp.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval = 100

# Layout files
tools.view.servlet.layout.directory = /
tools.view.servlet.layout.default.template =  Layout.vm
```

With a basic `index.vm` file in `src/main/resources` I clean build, run, visit `http://localhost/index.vm` and... 404

Steps I've tried

1. Setting `jetty.home` manually.

   ```
   File classesFolder;
   if ((classesFolder = new File("src\\main\\resources")).exists())
       rootPath = classesFolder.getAbsolutePath();
   else if ((classesFolder = new File("app")).exists())
       rootPath = classesFolder.getAbsolutePath();
   else
       rootPath = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
   log.debug("Current base: " + rootPath);
   server.setAttribute("jetty.home", rootPath);
   ```
2. Setting `servletHandler`'s context path.

   ```
   servletHandler.setContextPath("/");
   ```
3. Explicitly setting `tools.view.servlet.layout.directory` and `file.resource.loader.path` in the velocity properties file to `/src/main/resources/

The exception in all cases:

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource '/index.vm'
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:483) ~[velocity-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:354) ~[velocity-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1400) ~[velocity-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.getTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:422) ~[velocity-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityView.getTemplate(VelocityView.java:865) ~[velocity-tools-2.0.jar:2.0]
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityView.getTemplate(VelocityView.java:821) ~[velocity-tools-2.0.jar:2.0]
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityViewServlet.getTemplate(VelocityViewServlet.java:296) [velocity-tools-2.0.jar:2.0]
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityViewServlet.handleRequest(VelocityViewServlet.java:257) [velocity-tools-2.0.jar:2.0]
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityViewServlet.doRequest(VelocityViewServlet.java:217) [velocity-tools-2.0.jar:2.0]
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityViewServlet.doGet(VelocityViewServlet.java:182) [velocity-tools-2.0.jar:2.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:211) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1094) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1028) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:267) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:224) ~[jetty-server-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358) ~[jetty-io-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601) ~[jetty-util-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532) ~[jetty-util-9.0.4.v20130625.jar:9.0.4.v20130625]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I configure VelocityView to load resources when embedded inside Jetty?